# XMPP renegotiating the stream

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, xmpp

I have made my own [XMPP-PHP](https://github.com/Norgul/xmpp-php) library and have just implemented TLS support. The issue I'm having is with renegotiating the stream.

If I send `<starttls>`, I absolutely need to fetch a response from server first in order to be able to make the connection enable crypto:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket->connection, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT);
```

If I don't run the `getResponse()` method, which is basically:

```
public function getResponse(): string
{
    $response = '';
    while ($out = fgets($this->socket->connection)) {
        $response .= $out;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I am getting the following:

> Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code
>   1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in
>   /.../xmpp-php/src/XmppClient.php on line 121

This is making it impossible for me to establish TLS connection "behind the scenes". If I include the fetching response part, everything works as it should.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: In my understanding, this is expected. You need to get the proceed tag, and then only you can switch to TLS.

Comment: It makes sense to do the check whether I got the proceed tag before I actually send anything after it, but I am sure the verification goes through, so even if I set the `sleep(10)` before sending anything I will still get an error. Server has sent the tags, I just didn't read it. Why do I have to read it? Can server detect when I didn't read the socket buffer?

Comment: The issue is not the server but in your client. You must read it because you need to clean the received data buffer before switching your socket to TLS. The buffer needs to be empty because the client will otherwise read those data as part of the TLS negotiation and it will make it fail.